# Show $f_m:=\prod \limits_{i=0}^{m}(1+x^{2i+1})$ forms a cauchy sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cauchy-sequences

Let $f_m:=\prod \limits_{i=0}^{m}(1+x^{2i+1})$

Show that: $$(f_m)_{m\geq0} \text{ forms a Cauchy sequence in } \mathbb{C}[[]] $$

$\mathbb{C}[[x]]:={\sum_{n\geq0}a_nx^n \text{ | } a_n\in\mathbb{C}}$

I know that a sequence $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy consequence if for all $\epsilon>0$  there is a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $|x_n - x_m| < \epsilon \text{ } \forall n,m \geq N$.

$|\prod \limits_{i=0}^{n}(1+x^{2i+1}) - \prod \limits_{i=0}^{m}(1+x^{2i+1})|=| (1+x)(1+x^3)\cdots (1+x)^{2n+1} -  (1+x)(1+x^3)\cdots (1+x^{2m+1}|< \dots ????$

Can you please help me to do that?